# Set different corner radius for an ImageView programmatically

Tags: android, imageview, rounded-corners, gradientdrawable

I'm creating ImageView programmatically and I am trying to set different corner radius for each corner:

```
val imageView = ImageView(context)
imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
imageView.clipToOutline = true

val shape = GradientDrawable()
shape.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
shape.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(100f, 100f, 100f, 100f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)

imageView.background = shape
```

it's seems that `cornerRadii` does not work.

if i'm using `shape.cornerRadius = 100f` its working but for all the corners.

I've also tried to call `mutate()` before setting the `cornerRadii` but it did not affected the ImageView.